# Time series forecast not providing the correct forecast window

Tags: r, time-series, arima

So, I have counts for data between May 2016 and November 2016 for three groups.  Well, actually I have it for a lot of groups but I subsetted to three for this. I am using auto.arima and then trying to forecast the counts for 30 days but it won't.  It's forecasting out to January and even March for one group.  What am I doing wrong?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidyquant)
library(timetk)
library(sweep)
library(forecast)

sub <- structure(list(group = c("group_1", "group_1", "group_1", "group_1", 
                         "group_1", "group_1", "group_1", "group_1", "group_1", "group_1", 
                         "group_1", "group_1", "group_1", "group_1", "group_1", "group_1", 
                         "group_1", "group_1", "group_1", "group_1", "group_1", "group_1", 
                         "group_1", "group_1", "group_1", "group_1", "group_1", "group_1", 
                         "group_1", "group_1", "group_1", "group_1", "group_1", "group_1", 
                         "group_1", "group_1", "group_1", "group_1", "group_1", "group_1", 
                         "group_1", "group_1", "group_1", "group_1", "group_1", "group_1", 
                         "group_1", "group_1", "group_1", "group_1", "group_1", "group_1", 
                         "group_2", "group_2", "group_2", "group_2", "group_2", "group_2", 
                         "group_2", "group_2", "group_2", "group_2", "group_2", "group_2", 
                         "group_2", "group_2", "group_2", "group_2", "group_2", "group_2", 
                         "group_2", "group_2", "group_2", "group_2", "group_2", "group_2", 
                         "group_2", "group_2", "group_2", "group_2", "group_2", "group_2", 
                         "group_2", "group_2", "group_2", "group_2", "group_2", "group_2", 
                         "group_2", "group_2", "group_2", "group_2", "group_2", "group_3", 
                         "group_3", "group_3", "group_3", "group_3", "group_3", "group_3", 
                         "group_3", "group_3", "group_3", "group_3", "group_3", "group_3", 
                         "group_3", "group_3", "group_3", "group_3", "group_3", "group_3", 
                         "group_3", "group_3", "group_3", "group_3", "group_3", "group_3", 
                         "group_3", "group_3", "group_3", "group_3"), date = structure(c(16934, 
                                                                                         16947, 16952, 16955, 16959, 16962, 16965, 16968, 16971, 16974, 
                                                                                         16977, 16980, 16983, 16986, 16989, 16992, 16995, 16998, 17001, 
                                                                                         17004, 17007, 17010, 17013, 17016, 17019, 17022, 17025, 17028, 
                                                                                         17031, 17034, 17037, 17040, 17043, 17046, 17049, 17052, 17055, 
                                                                                         17058, 17061, 17064, 17067, 17070, 17073, 17076, 17079, 17082, 
                                                                                         17085, 17088, 17091, 17094, 17097, 17101, 16963, 16968, 16974, 
                                                                                         16977, 16983, 16986, 16989, 16992, 16995, 16998, 17001, 17004, 
                                                                                         17007, 17010, 17013, 17016, 17019, 17022, 17025, 17028, 17031, 
                                                                                         17034, 17037, 17040, 17043, 17046, 17049, 17052, 17055, 17061, 
                                                                                         17066, 17071, 17074, 17079, 17082, 17088, 17093, 17099, 17103, 
                                                                                         17108, 17113, 16994, 17001, 17004, 17008, 17012, 17016, 17019, 
                                                                                         17022, 17025, 17029, 17032, 17035, 17038, 17042, 17045, 17049, 
                                                                                         17052, 17056, 17059, 17062, 17067, 17071, 17075, 17080, 17086, 
                                                                                         17092, 17099, 17104, 17108), class = "Date"), count = c(65, 12, 
                                                                                                                                                 46, 33, 19, 18, 56, 21, 50, 13, 80, 70, 56, 59, 78, 96, 111, 
                                                                                                                                                 140, 147, 132, 86, 96, 186, 169, 153, 106, 94, 80, 134, 172, 
                                                                                                                                                 217, 148, 106, 94, 102, 74, 132, 75, 108, 50, 81, 78, 38, 91, 
                                                                                                                                                 109, 44, 101, 82, 102, 28, 44, 48, 56, 82, 64, 74, 16, 69, 87, 
                                                                                                                                                 11, 97, 144, 41, 95, 99, 83, 54, 62, 131, 92, 90, 104, 113, 51, 
                                                                                                                                                 74, 72, 84, 36, 25, 94, 100, 58, 32, 62, 41, 70, 17, 80, 37, 
                                                                                                                                                 53, 63, 67, 73, 63, 27, 36, 17, 55, 16, 38, 48, 97, 88, 84, 39, 
                                                                                                                                                 34, 24, 60, 61, 10, 25, 20, 85, 21, 78, 85, 16, 16, 82, 81, 53, 
                                                                                                                                                 25)), row.names = c(NA, -122L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
                                                                                                                                                 ))


                                
dta <- sub %>%
  mutate(order = as_date((date))) %>%
  select(-date)

dta_nest <- dta %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  nest()

## Create a daily Date object
inds <- seq(min(sub$date, na.rm=T), max(sub$date, na.rm=T), by = "day")

# Create the time series data
dta_ts <- dta_nest %>%
  mutate(data.ts = map(.x       = data, 
                       .f       = tk_ts, 
                       select   = -order, 
                       start    = c(2022, as.numeric(format(inds[1], "%j")))),
         freq     = 365)


# Fit ARIMA
dta_fit <- dta_ts %>%
  mutate(fit.arima = map(data.ts, auto.arima))

# Obtain the augmented fitted and residual values
augment_fit_arima <- dta_fit %>%
  mutate(augment = map(fit.arima, sw_augment, timetk_idx = TRUE, rename_index = "date")) %>%
  unnest(augment)

# Forecast
dta_fcast <- dta_fit %>%
  mutate(fcast.arima = map(fit.arima, forecast, h = 30))  # 30 day forecast

dta_fcast_tidy <- dta_fcast %>%
  mutate(sweep = map(fcast.arima, sw_sweep, fitted = FALSE, timetk_idx = TRUE)) %>%
  unnest(sweep)

# Plot the forecast
dta_fcast_tidy %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = index, y = count, color = key, group = group)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lo.95, ymax = hi.95), 
              fill = "#D5DBFF", color = NA, size = 0) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lo.80, ymax = hi.80, fill = key), 
              fill = "#596DD5", color = NA, size = 0, alpha = 0.8) +
  geom_line() +
  labs(title = "Counts by Group",
       subtitle = "ARIMA Model Forecasts",
       x = "", y = "Units") +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "2 weeks", date_labels = "%b %d") +
  scale_color_tq() +
  scale_fill_tq() +
  facet_wrap(~ group, scales = "free_y", ncol = 1) +
  theme_tq() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

Here is the plot I am getting:

[image]

Comment: Awesome posting of data and code @JeniFav, allowing @Mitchell O'Hara-Wild's super useful answer.

In addition to Mitch's comments about sw_seep, the tk_ts call in creating dta_ts is breaking the time values:
`plot(dta_ts[[3]][[1]])
plot(dta_ts[[3]][[2]])
plot(dta_ts[[3]][[3]])`
The fable approach using tsibbles identifies the problem:
`.data contains implicit gaps in time. You should check your data and convert implicit gaps into explicit missing values using tsibble::fill_gaps() if required.` and suggested a fix.

Answer (score 2):

The forecasts from `auto.arima()` are 30 days ahead, however your processing of these forecast objects with `sw_sweep()` is mangling the dates of these forecasts.

```r
# Forecast
dta_fcast <- dta_fit %>%
  mutate(fcast.arima = map(fit.arima, forecast, h = 30))  # 30 day forecast

dta_fcast$fcast.arima %>% map(~ length(.$mean))
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 30
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 30
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] 30

dta_fcast_tidy <- dta_fcast %>%
  mutate(sweep = map(fcast.arima, sw_sweep, fitted = FALSE, timetk_idx = TRUE)) %>%
  unnest(sweep)

dta_fcast_tidy %>% 
  filter(!is.na(lo.95)) %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  summarise(min(index), max(index), max(index) - min(index))
#> # A tibble: 3 × 4
#>   group   `min(index)` `max(index)` `max(index) - min(index)`
#>   <chr>   <date>       <date>       <drtn>                   
#> 1 group_1 2016-10-30   2017-01-25    87 days                 
#> 2 group_2 2016-11-11   2017-02-06    87 days                 
#> 3 group_3 2016-11-07   2017-03-03   116 days
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

These issues largely stem from how `ts` objects used by the `{forecast}` package represent points in time. It works well for monthly, quarterly and annual data but has issues with weekly, daily and sub-daily frequencies. This is why we've moved to tidy time series formats (via the `{tsibble}` package) for representing time series data. The use of `ts` objects is also incompatible with the many missing values that exist in your data.

Representing the data using `{tsibble}` and forecasting with `{fable}` can be done, with a little extra work, given the data you have.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(fable)
#> Loading required package: fabletools
library(tsibble)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'tsibble'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, union

sub <- structure(list(group = c("group_1", "group_1", "group_1", "group_1", 
                                "group_1", "group_1", "group_1", "group_1", "group_1", "group_1", 
                                "group_1", "group_1", "group_1", "group_1", "group_1", "group_1", 
                                "group_1", "group_1", "group_1", "group_1", "group_1", "group_1", 
                                "group_1", "group_1", "group_1", "group_1", "group_1", "group_1", 
                                "group_1", "group_1", "group_1", "group_1", "group_1", "group_1", 
                                "group_1", "group_1", "group_1", "group_1", "group_1", "group_1", 
                                "group_1", "group_1", "group_1", "group_1", "group_1", "group_1", 
                                "group_1", "group_1", "group_1", "group_1", "group_1", "group_1", 
                                "group_2", "group_2", "group_2", "group_2", "group_2", "group_2", 
                                "group_2", "group_2", "group_2", "group_2", "group_2", "group_2", 
                                "group_2", "group_2", "group_2", "group_2", "group_2", "group_2", 
                                "group_2", "group_2", "group_2", "group_2", "group_2", "group_2", 
                                "group_2", "group_2", "group_2", "group_2", "group_2", "group_2", 
                                "group_2", "group_2", "group_2", "group_2", "group_2", "group_2", 
                                "group_2", "group_2", "group_2", "group_2", "group_2", "group_3", 
                                "group_3", "group_3", "group_3", "group_3", "group_3", "group_3", 
                                "group_3", "group_3", "group_3", "group_3", "group_3", "group_3", 
                                "group_3", "group_3", "group_3", "group_3", "group_3", "group_3", 
                                "group_3", "group_3", "group_3", "group_3", "group_3", "group_3", 
                                "group_3", "group_3", "group_3", "group_3"), date = structure(c(16934, 
                                                                                                16947, 16952, 16955, 16959, 16962, 16965, 16968, 16971, 16974, 
                                                                                                16977, 16980, 16983, 16986, 16989, 16992, 16995, 16998, 17001, 
                                                                                                17004, 17007, 17010, 17013, 17016, 17019, 17022, 17025, 17028, 
                                                                                                17031, 17034, 17037, 17040, 17043, 17046, 17049, 17052, 17055, 
                                                                                                17058, 17061, 17064, 17067, 17070, 17073, 17076, 17079, 17082, 
                                                                                                17085, 17088, 17091, 17094, 17097, 17101, 16963, 16968, 16974, 
                                                                                                16977, 16983, 16986, 16989, 16992, 16995, 16998, 17001, 17004, 
                                                                                                17007, 17010, 17013, 17016, 17019, 17022, 17025, 17028, 17031, 
                                                                                                17034, 17037, 17040, 17043, 17046, 17049, 17052, 17055, 17061, 
                                                                                                17066, 17071, 17074, 17079, 17082, 17088, 17093, 17099, 17103, 
                                                                                                17108, 17113, 16994, 17001, 17004, 17008, 17012, 17016, 17019, 
                                                                                                17022, 17025, 17029, 17032, 17035, 17038, 17042, 17045, 17049, 
                                                                                                17052, 17056, 17059, 17062, 17067, 17071, 17075, 17080, 17086, 
                                                                                                17092, 17099, 17104, 17108), class = "Date"), count = c(65, 12, 
                                                                                                                                                        46, 33, 19, 18, 56, 21, 50, 13, 80, 70, 56, 59, 78, 96, 111, 
                                                                                                                                                        140, 147, 132, 86, 96, 186, 169, 153, 106, 94, 80, 134, 172, 
                                                                                                                                                        217, 148, 106, 94, 102, 74, 132, 75, 108, 50, 81, 78, 38, 91, 
                                                                                                                                                        109, 44, 101, 82, 102, 28, 44, 48, 56, 82, 64, 74, 16, 69, 87, 
                                                                                                                                                        11, 97, 144, 41, 95, 99, 83, 54, 62, 131, 92, 90, 104, 113, 51, 
                                                                                                                                                        74, 72, 84, 36, 25, 94, 100, 58, 32, 62, 41, 70, 17, 80, 37, 
                                                                                                                                                        53, 63, 67, 73, 63, 27, 36, 17, 55, 16, 38, 48, 97, 88, 84, 39, 
                                                                                                                                                        34, 24, 60, 61, 10, 25, 20, 85, 21, 78, 85, 16, 16, 82, 81, 53, 
                                                                                                                                                        25)), row.names = c(NA, -122L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
                                                                                                                                                        ))


dta <- sub %>% 
  as_tsibble(index = date, key = group)

dta %>% autoplot(count)
```

[image]

```r
dta %>% 
  # ARIMA() without specification will automatically choose a model, like auto.arima()
  model(ARIMA(count)) %>% 
  forecast(h = 30) %>% 
  autoplot(dta)
#> Warning: 3 errors (1 unique) encountered for ARIMA(count)
#> [3] .data contains implicit gaps in time. You should check your data and convert implicit gaps into explicit missing values using `tsibble::fill_gaps()` if required.
#> Warning in max(ids, na.rm = TRUE): no non-missing arguments to max; returning
#> -Inf

#> Warning in max(ids, na.rm = TRUE): no non-missing arguments to max; returning
#> -Inf

#> Warning in max(ids, na.rm = TRUE): no non-missing arguments to max; returning
#> -Inf

#> Warning in max(ids, na.rm = TRUE): no non-missing arguments to max; returning
#> -Inf

#> Warning in max(ids, na.rm = TRUE): no non-missing arguments to max; returning
#> -Inf

#> Warning in max(ids, na.rm = TRUE): no non-missing arguments to max; returning
#> -Inf
#> Warning: Removed 90 rows containing missing values (`()`).
```

[image]

The `{fable}` package will also try to prevent you from making common analysis errors. In this case, the data contains implicit gaps in time. ARIMA can handle missing values in the data, but they need to be made explicit.

```r
dta %>% 
  fill_gaps() %>% 
  autoplot(count) +
  geom_point()
#> Warning: Removed 312 rows containing missing values (`geom_point()`).
```

[image]

Wow! There’s lots of missing data here! So much that there are no observations made in back-to-back days.
This will probably cause some issues with the model, but let's try it anyway:

```r
dta %>% 
  fill_gaps() %>% 
  model(ARIMA(count)) %>% 
  forecast(h = 30) %>% 
  autoplot(dta, level = c(80, 95))
```

[image]

There are the forecasts, but the data seems to end on different days, so the forecasts are for different time periods.
We can fill the gaps in the data across groups to fix this:

```r
dta %>% 
  fill_gaps(.full = TRUE) %>% 
  model(ARIMA(count)) %>% 
  forecast(h = 30) %>% 
  autoplot(dta, level = c(80, 95))
```

[image]

Since there are so many missing values in the data, you might prefer to forecast at a different frequency.
Instead, let's aggregate the data from daily to weekly using the average count
(note: this may not be appropriate depending on the nature of the data).

```r
dta_week <- dta %>% 
  index_by(week = yearweek(date)) %>% 
  group_by_key() %>% 
  summarise(count = mean(count)) %>% 
  fill_gaps(.full = TRUE)

dta_week %>% 
  autoplot(count)
#> Warning: Removed 16 rows containing missing values (`geom_line()`).
```

[image]

Much fewer missing values now. Let’s forecast again 4 weeks ahead.

```r
dta_week %>% 
  model(ARIMA(count)) %>% 
  forecast(h = 4) %>% 
  autoplot(dta_week, level = c(80, 95))
#> Warning: Removed 16 rows containing missing values (`geom_line()`).
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

You can also customise these forecast plots, as you have done above. You might like to use the `{ggdist}` package (especially `ggdist::stat_lineribbon()`) for plotting the intervals.

Comment: [Forecasting: Principles and Practice (3rd ed)](https://otexts.com/fpp3/) is a great resource for learning the tidyverts (tsibble/fable) tools and philosophy.

Comment: Thanks @Mitchell O'Hara-Wild for this solution!  I am excited to try  it on my full dataset (which has a lot more groups).  I will come back and let you know how it worked out.   But thank you, also, for the very thorough explanation of WHY this is happening!

Comment: @Mitchell O'Hara-Wild - this is a silly question but is there a way to make autoplot put the lines in one panel?  My actual data as about 60 groups and those 60 different panels aren't able to be seen.  I know it's messy on one panel but I have a method to my madness.

Comment: Thanks @Isaiah for the fpp3 reference, it's definitely worth a read to learn more about forecasting in general! JeniFav: autoplot() is intended to give a basic plot with limited customisation - good for a quick look but not appropriate for designing the perfect plot. Plotting 60 series at once is tricky regardless of how you do it - either too many facets or so many lines atop each other you can't see anything. Facets are usually best, you can export a larger plot window. Alternatively plot from scratch using ggdist, or filter() out series of interest and plot them separately with autoplot().

Comment: `dta_fore <- dta |> 
  fill_gaps() |> 
  model(ARIMA(count)) |> 
  forecast(h = 30)`

    
`ggplot() +
  geom_line(data = dta_fore, aes(x = date, y = .mean, colour = group)) +
  geom_line(data = dta, aes(x = date, y = count, colour = group))`

Comment: @Isaiah, yeah, that looks crazy with all 60 but it has some use (mostly for demo to someone else) so thanks!  Thanks to both of you for helping figure this out!